# Using "FileStream" with text files in the resources

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I'm new to coding and was wandering if there was a way to use filestream to read txt files within the resources.

The code is:

```
    Dim decHolder As Decimal

    Dim F As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Thunderlol\Desktop\Kees 2\Program 2.0\Resources\Thresh Dress.txt")
    decHolder = F.ReadToEnd
```

The problem is every time that I try to see the value, it returns as nothing. I have done file stream from a file, the reason I have to do it from the resources is that this is for a college project and my tutor has made this a requirement.

Context: I want the user to be able to change a price, the price will start from the value within the txt document. When the user changes the price, the txt document will change to what ever the user has typed in.

Currently, my problem is that everytime I try to use a text file from my resources, the value returns as "0". The file has been checked the the value is in there, so why is it returning as 0

Comment: Assigning a string to a decimal usually will not work.

Comment: and - is resources a directory? or are you talking about embedded resources?

Comment: Hey, sorry, the embedded resources within the project

Answer (score 0):

Embedded resources are accessed a bit differently.

```
Dim line As String = String.Empty
Dim value As Decimal = 0

Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetNamedResourceStream("[program namespace].Thresh Dress.txt")
  line = reader.ReadLine
  Decimal.TryParse(line, value)
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just one final question:I'm getting an error saying "assembly is not declared it may be inaccessible due to its protection level" Any ideas?

Comment: `Assembly` is a class that lives in the `System.Reflection` namespace.  Either fully qualify the classname in your code (`System.Reflection.Assembly`), or add a namespace import at the top of your code file (`Imports System.Reflection`)